# how to perform an action in iphone application on click in webview

Tags: iphone, authentication, uiwebview

I need to implement a functionality such that I have there is a login screen which sends an http request packet, gets a json response(a boolean and a routing link) and opens a webview. I have done this successfully. But further what I need to do is that when I click sign out in the webview, I should get back to the native login screen.How can I achieve that?

Comment: you can use touches began at the particular location of signout button

Comment: this cant work since user can scroll down the page.

Answer (score 1):

Check this call back method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

}
```

You get this call back when you click link in webview.

Comment: can u please provide any example?